# Is what i think Magnetism is, Magnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, space

So, i was randomly thinking about magnets one day and decided to try and figure out what Magnetism actually is. This is what i came up with: Magnetism, the magnetic field of an object, is a form of energy that is attached to specific matter (Magnets), this energy is either + or -. When two +'s or two -'s are within each others field, the space in the middle, like with gravity, pushes the matter away. But if there is a + and a - in each others fields, the space in the middle pulls together. So magnetic energy that is attached to a matter object gains "power" when another magnetic object is put into it's field, in the sense that when this happens the magnetic energy interacts with the space around it. Am i right? On the right track? Completely wrong? Or... what?

Comment: Nope! Mostly wrong. A magnetic field stores energy, but never comes alone in a + or - alone. It's true that if you put one magnet into the field of another magnet, you put it in a higher energy state and have to use power to put it there, but it's not really the "power of the magnet" that makes it try to move back. See also: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=qjmtJpzoW0o

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy I think there is a way of understanding the poster's question that makes it not "totally wrong".  The language is clearly not standard physics language, but we do conceive that the space around a magnet is filled with a field, and that it is that field which acts on another magnet.  And, as you point out, bringing two like poles together increases *something*, but we would call it energy, not power.  Still, the wording of the question makes it difficult to give a good answer.  For example, the phrase "the space in the middle pushes outward" is hard to interpret.

Comment: `When two +'s or two -'s are within each others field, the space in the middle, like with gravity, pulls the matter together` No, equal poles reject each other. `But if there is a + and a - in each others fields, the space in the middle pushes outward` No, different poles attract each other. It seems you switched those two.

Comment: Yeah i just realized that, sorry :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but it is a bit more complicated than that.

At every point in space around a magnet there is a magnetic field. This field isn't just $+$ or $-$'s, instead there is an arrow (a vector, in mathematical language) pointing in some direction, as in this picture: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field#mediaviewer/File:VFPt_cylindrical_magnet_thumb.svg. The arrows point from north to south. I will explain what these arrows mean physically below.

If we put two magnets near each other, then they both create a field and, like you suggest, we have to add the values at each point together to find out what the field looks like for the two magnet system. Adding arrows is similar to adding your $+$ and $-$'s; to add the arrows you put the arrows head to tail: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ef/Vector_addition.png

We can see that in this framework, two arrows pointing in opposite directions (and of the same length) cancel out, just like $+$ and $-$ do. The resulting field around two magnets looks like this: http://www.matsuk12.us/cms/lib/AK01000953/Centricity/Domain/1802/Magnet/attract.gif, or like this http://www.northeastern.edu/sunlab/mom/img/How%20Magnets%20Work/magneticFieldLinesRepulsive.gif, depending on whether the poles are the same or opposite.

Now for the physics; the vector field around the magnet does correspond to the force a magnetic object would experience if it were at that point, just like the gravitational field tells you the force a massive object would experience, so you are completely correct in your analogy. This is why iron filings line up as they do around a magnet. NeuroFuzzy has said in the comments that the magnetic field stores energy, and this is true. The video he links gives a very good explanation of how magnets "work".

I know this doesn't exactly answer your question, but this problem is also discussed in Neuro's video, but I hope it gives you some understanding of magnetism.